# Pom.xml: connect timedout and modelversion missing error

Tags: java, xml, maven, pom.xml

I get the following error on eclipse for the pom.xml file.

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - connect timed out
    - Failure to transfer org.jibx:jibx-maven-plugin:pom:1.2.4 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be 
     reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.jibx:jibx-maven-plugin:pom:1.2.4 from/to central 
     (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out
    - Project build error: 'modelVersion' is missing.
```

The pom.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.koushik.javabrains</groupId>
      <artifactId>testagain</artifactId> 
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>

      <name>JarName</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      </properties>

      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jibx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>bind</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Any help would be great. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse?

Comment: I've posted my findings in an answer below. What's weird is your _timeout_ issue. Are you behind some kind of corporate firewall? Are u using http proxy to connect to internet? How does your maven `settings.xml` look like? You can have proxies / mirrors configured there that block access to specific (i.e. not approved by the corporation) artifacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there's something wrong with the `jibx-maven-plugin` version `1.2.4`.
It has a dependency to:

```
org.jibx.config:jibx-parent:pom:3-SNAPSHOT
```

which could not be found in Maven Central. I created a simple project with your pom.xml and - when I try building it with `maven` from command line - I get this:

> [ERROR] Plugin org.jibx:jibx-maven-plugin:1.2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jibx:jibx-maven-plugin:jar:1.2.4: Could not find artifact org.jibx.config:jibx-parent:pom:3-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]

However, after upgrading my `pom.xml` to use version `1.2.6` the problem disappears, and Eclipse stops complaining* about the plugin as well.

* it still complains that the *plugin execution is not covered by the lifecycle configuration*, but [there are solutions to this as well](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html).